# How to fix "Did not find mosh server startup message." when connecting from OS X to Linux router?

Tags: linux, networking, macos, router, mosh

I did install `Mosh` on (1) a Mac OS X 10.9.5 machine, (2) a Debian 8 VM, and (3) as [Entware-ng](https://github.com/Entware-ng/Entware-ng/wiki) package on a router that runs an embedded Linux. Mosh connection from Mac (1) to (2) Debian is **ok**. Mosh connection from (1) Mac to (3) Linux embedded router **fails** with the message:

## /usr/local/bin/mosh: Did not find mosh server startup message.

Environment:

- Mosh version on the Mac is 1.2.5.
- All machines are configured to ssh login with certificates.
- Mac OS X shell is zsh.
- `/usr/local/bin` is in the $PATH of the Mac OS X
- Mac Terminal application is [iTerm 2](https://www.iterm2.com/).1.4
- Debian 8 is running in a 10.x pvm_nat LAN: parallels virtual machine with shared networking, that Parallels runs on the same Mac.
- Command used to connect to Debian `$ mosh username@10.x.x.x`
- Router rt-n56u is running at IP 192.168.x using a cabled LAN
- Command to connnect from Mac to router is: `$ mosh username@192.168.x.x`
- Linux router is running [Padavan firmware](https://bitbucket.org/padavan/rt-n56u) [RT-N56U_3.4.3.9-099_base.trx](https://bitbucket.org/padavan/rt-n56u/downloads/RT-N56U_3.4.3.9-099_base.trx)

Regression

1. I did try to disable the Little Snitch firewall on the Mac with no improvement, still:
   `/usr/local/bin/mosh: Did not find mosh server startup message.`
2. I did also try to start a debug session using:
   `$ ssh -S none -o ProxyCommand='mosh --fake-proxy -- %h %p' -n -tt user@192.168.x.x -- 'mosh-server new'`
   `MOSH IP 192.168.x.x`
   `Connection to 192.168.x.x closed.`
3. I commented out `SendEnv` on the Mac:
   `$ cat /etc/ssh_config | grep SendEnv`
   `# SendEnv LANG LC_*`
4. I have tried to disable the firewall on the router, which doesn't make any difference:
   `/usr/local/bin/mosh: Did not find mosh server startup message.`

The rt-n56u log displays this:

```
May  3 00:42:15 dropbear[819]: Child connection from 192.168.x.y:50824
May  3 00:42:17 dropbear[819]: Pubkey auth succeeded for 'username' with key md5 2c:...:94 from 192.168.x.y:50824
May  3 00:42:18 dropbear[820]: ioctl(TIOCSCTTY): Input/output error
May  3 00:42:18 dropbear[820]: /dev/pts/0: No such file or directory
May  3 00:42:18 dropbear[820]: open /dev/tty failed - could not set controlling tty: No such device or address
May  3 00:42:18 dropbear[819]: Exit (username): Disconnect received
```

On the rt-n56u:

```
# ls -l /dev/pts/*
crw--w--w-    1 username   root      136,   0 May  3 00:45 /dev/pts/0
# ls -l /dev/tty
crw-rw----    1 username   root        5,   0 Jan  1  2015 /dev/tty
```

What can be done to fix the `mosh` connection from this Mac to rt-n56u router?

Answer (score 4):

Check where the `mosh-server` binary is installed in the embedded Linux, and pass that path to the `server` option in your `mosh` command.

Suppose the `mosh-server` binary is installed in `/usr/bin/` directory in the embedded Linux, then run `mosh` like:

```
$ mosh --server=/usr/bin/mosh-server username@192.168.x.x
```

Answer (score 3):

I hope this helps, this problem also happened to me with same message, I'm not an expert yet i solved this way:

Analog to your config (3) and (1) my server is running Ubuntu Server 18.04 and my client is an iMac running Mojave.

1. On the server y run:

   `$ echo $LANG`

   `en_US.UTF-8`
2. Then search the mosh-server path, it was on `/usr/bin/mosh-server`
3. On the Mac change the last line in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` to `SendEnv LANG en_US.UTF-8` like the previus server output.
4. The command i use for mosh is like this indicating the mosh-server path and ssh port:

   `$ mosh --server=/usr/bin/mosh-server user@host.domain.org --ssh="ssh -p XXXX"`

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser!  The original post configuration doesn't match the configuration in your answer, so unless you are suggesting that they change their configuration I don't know how useful this is. It may be helpful for you take a moment to take the SuperUser [tour].  If you follow the norms of the SuperUser community and approach it with an attitude of helping others too, it will serve you well.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @Rey Juna, I edit the answer to clarify the reference to the question and read de SuperUser tour and I'm hopping to help accordingly.

Comment: Perfect! Worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

According to the mock [debug wiki page](https://github.com/mobile-shell/mosh/wiki/Debugging-and-Theory), what you should do next is:

```
 ssh -S none -o ProxyCommand='mosh --fake-proxy -- %h %p' -n -tt user@server.com -- 'mosh-server new'
```

and see what it says.

Answer (score 0):

Export LC_CTYPE to value of LANG(echo $LANG) of that of the mosh server.

Comment: Can you expand on how the OP would do this? Please take a look at [answer] and take our [tour].

Answer (score 0):

This question was asked 7 years ago now, I hope all 9k visitors since then have by now found a way to avoid having to enter the —server everytime.

This is mine:

```
mbj@m2 ~ % echo PATH=/opt/homebrew/bin:\$PATH >> ~/.zshenv
```